# Is it possible to get full URL(include domain) within Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I found the tag `{% url path.to.view %}` can only return the path of URL, how can I get the full URL with domain name?

Actually, what I want to do is, adding a link which point to **another** view of my site. But `{% url path.to.view %}` can only get the path of my view. In result, the link cannot point to what I want.

My solution is using `HttpRequest.get_host()` in first view to get domain and pass it to template by Context. Then, in template(html file), splice to the full url address. Like this:`<a href="http://{{ domain }}{% url path.to.view %}?param={{param}}">Foo</a>`.

In short, I just want to get domain. Sorry for my unclear description! @Hans's answer is great, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/):

Use the method `build_absolute_uri()` on the request object.